# Slots machine in JS - stack call size exceed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a basic (non animated) slot machine but am getting an error with stack size.

I'm hoping some one can explain what the cause is =/

My Error :

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Code:

```
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
              function( callback,  element){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
              };
    })();
var img_array = new Array('fire','life','lightning','rain','snow','sound','sun');


function roll(start_time){
var seconds_passed = new Date().getTime() / 1000 - start_time ;

if(seconds_passed < 3){
    slot = 1;
    while(slot < 4){
        randno = Math.floor(Math.random()*img_array.length);
        document.getElementById("slot"+slot).innerHTML = '<img src="'+img_array[randno]+'.png"/>';
        slot++;
        }
    requestAnimFrame(roll(start_time));     
    } else {
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = 'Roll The Slots Again?';
    document.getElementById("start").onclick = function(){start(); };
    }
    return false;
}

function start(){
start_time = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = 'Processing......';
roll(start_time);
}

window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = 'Roll The Slots';
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function(){start(); };
}
```

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just calls `roll` recursively for three seconds, which will exceed the maximum call stack size:

```
requestAnimFrame(roll(start_time));
```

You probably meant:

```
requestAnimFrame(function() {
    roll(start_time);
});
```

Comment: the `requestAnimFrame` function, as defined, does not accept any arguments.

Comment: @David: Yes, it does. See the parentheses at the end? It's immediately invoked and returns a function that does, in fact, take an argument.

Comment: Just to add is there anyway i can slow my AnimFrame down =/ without the use of set interval ? It calls very quickly too fast for my eyes ...

Comment: Ah, I didn't spot that. This sneaky function-wrapping get confusing after a while.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a recursive call with no guard expression.

`function roll(start_time)` makes a call to `roll` (as the value argument to requestAnimFrame), right after the `while()` block ends.